# How to import LLVM on a cmake based bitbake recipe?

Tags: cmake, llvm, yocto

I have a CMake project that needs LLVM to build, so I have: `Find_Package(LLVM REQUIRED)` on my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

This works fine when building on my system, but if I try to build this project using bitbake, then LLVM is not found by cmake:

```
|   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM" with any of
|   the following names:
| 
|     LLVMConfig.cmake
|     llvm-config.cmake
```

I have already included `llvm` and `llvm-common` on my recipe's `DEPENDS`, and llvm libraries seems to be installed on the sysroot, but I couldn't find the CMake files anywhere. On the `llvm` [recipe](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/llvm/llvm_git.bb?h=warrior) there are two suspicious lines, but there is probably a reason they are there:

```
    # Remove unnecessary cmake files
    rm -rf ${D}${libdir}/${LLVM_DIR}/cmake
```

So what is the proper way to use  LLVM from CMake? I'd be really thankful if the proposed solution doesn't involve hacking the original llvm recipe.

Comment: It indeed seem that the installation script removes CMake config files. I would report a bug to the distribution.